# What style cabinets are these?

Tags: cabinets

What is this style of face frames and drawer faces called?

I can see that they are inset and have a newel, but I’d like to know the name of the style of the doors and faces so I can order similar ones.

[image]

Comment: this seems pretty close to the door style: https://www.fastcabinetdoors.com/cabinet-doors/inset-panel-cabinet-doors/estrella.html

Comment: ah hah! the face frames are called “beaded face frames”

Comment: Why not take this picture to your local cabinet maker/kitchen cabinet design center/home improvement store and simply "point and grunt"? While they might not have a "name" for the style (though they likely do), they'll definitely be able to bring you to the location in the show room or the page(s) in the catalog where they have items most similar to this and you can begin to put your order together. Oddly, there is a toe-kick on the cabinet at the back, but _not_ one the cabinet closest to camera. IMHO, you should stick with one or the other, but of course, that "opinion"...